# Full Access permission user not able to delete item within a calendar list

Tags: 2013, permissions, error, sharepoint-calendar, access-denied

Issue is occurring with a single calendar with multiple (9) calendar color coded views.

The issue is that a user (with full control) has been receiving error messages when they try to delete a single entry from this SharePoint Calendar. The user however does not experience problems when they create and/or delete the entire list/calendar.

Error message looks like:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The User [user] is not permitted to perform the deletion of Item [List].

We have two full control users, would this be an issue?

We have tried removing/re-adding her, with different permission levels with no luck.

Comment: Are they able to delete an item from a non-calendar list view?

Comment: I had the same issue as SCadmin i couldnt even delete and was tracing in the logs without any real information other than what was being given. Luckily I had just 3 out of 100 sites i created via powershell with the issue. tried restoring to the day is was created withthe same issue. looking at all the site sizes in the comvault restore manager i noticed that the sites that had the issue all had a slightly diffrent size( 3.84Mb not 3.8Mb) .I had to delete and recreate the site to resolve this issue (not ideal). If anyone finds an answer to this please update this thread

Comment: Does the calendar item the user is trying to delete have broken permission inheritance from the calendar list?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to another view of the list and try to delete the item from there. It could be an issue with the view

Comment: I created items in a few different views and then tried to delete those items. Unfortunately I received the same error message for each calendar view.